# At what point in a refinance application should I be able to get a rate lock?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance, mortgage-rate

I've submitted my URLA, credit is checked and appraisal is scheduled. The broker has sent a disclosure pack that he wants me to sign and return with all documentation in order to start underwriting. Should I be able to get a rate lock before underwriting starts, or is this only possible after I've submitted all the signed forms and documentation?

Comment: Ask the lender or loan agent. I've seen them allow a 30-day rate lock at just about any time. The question is whether the lock will last until you're ready to sign the loan, meaning all other paperwork is complete... which, for a refi, really shouldn't be a problem. Of course locking the rate is optional, depending on how much and in which directions you expect the rate to change during that period.

Comment: The broker insists that they can't lock until they get the signed disclosures and documentation. I suspect I'm being misled.

Comment: I would certainly expect that you would have a firm rate before going to underwriting.  I would expect you to have a firm rate before the appraisal, as that's usually a cost you bear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a former mortgage broker, I can tell you the rate should be locked upon your signature, that day.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, you mean my signature on the disclosures, or the URLA?